# Return null data for everything

Tags: android, parse-platform

if I extends any object from **ParseObject** or **ParseUser**, it everytime returns me null for every variable it contains. For example:

```
public class User extends ParseUser {

    private boolean emailVerified;
    private String facebookID;

    private int fiveHundredID;
    private String fiveHundredUsername;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private String canonicalFirstName;
    private String canonicalLastName;

    private Date birthday;
    private Photo profilePicture;

    private int followeeCount;
    private int followerCount;

}
```

And then I call **User.fetchInBackground()**, it doesn't fill any variable except objectId, email and the others variable, that are contained only in ParseUser class. Of course, I already initialize Parse in App class like:

```
Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .applicationId(Const.X_PARSE_APPLICATION_ID)
        .clientKey(Const.X_PARSE_REST_API_KEY)
        .server(Const.PARSE_SERVER_URL)
        .enableLocalDataStore()
        //.addNetworkInterceptor(new JsonInterceptor())
        .build());

ParseObject.registerSubclass(User.class);
```

Im not using any proguard, because Im testing that on the Debug version. Any help? Also when I have enabled LocalDataStore, it store my current User. But when I call fetchInBackground(), it returns me the same data as Local data are stored. Also when I call unpinInBackground() and after that I'll call fetchInBackground(), it still returns me the local data stored in DB.

Any help?

Many thanks

Comment: did you add the model annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this annotation just above your model class :

```
@ParseClassName("User")
public class User extends ParseUser {
    ...
```

Comment: @Abdenaceur_Lichiheb well, I can't to add ParseClassName, because it throws the error: **com.parse.ParseUser cannot be cast to <package_name>.Parse.User**

Comment: @user997777 Well you cannot register object without adding that annotation, because that class is not going to be recognized, can you paste your error.

Comment: @Abdenaceur_Lichiheb I already checked, what returned to me and it gave me the correct data from server. There is just a problem, that it looks like that it doesn't update data in my local data store and returned me the old data from data store. Do you know this problem?